# linear function, operator norm

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let be $\Phi:V\to W$ a linear function between the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with the norms $\|\cdot\|_V$ and $\|\cdot\|_W$. Prove that
$$\|\Phi\|_{\mathcal{L}(V,W)}=\kappa_{abs},$$
while
$$\|\Phi\|_{\mathcal{L}(V,W)}:=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|\Phi(x)\|_W}{\|x\|_V}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|\Phi(x)\|_W$$
and
$$\kappa_{abs}:=\limsup_{x\to x_0}\frac{\|\Phi(x)-\Phi(x_0)\|_W}{\|x-x_0\|_V}.$$
How can I prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Well @froggie,

my solution is:

$$\begin{align*} 
\|\Phi\|_{\mathcal{L}(V,W)} &= \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|\Phi(x)\|_W}{\|x\|_V} = \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|\Phi(x+\tilde{x}-\tilde{x})\|_W}{\|x\|_V}\\
(\Phi\text{ is linear})|&=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|\Phi(x+\tilde{x})-\Phi(\tilde{x})\|_W}{\|x\|_V} \\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\|\Phi(x+\tilde{x})-\Phi(\tilde{x})\|_W}{\|x\|_V}\\
&=\kappa_{abs}.
\end{align*}$$